# I cannot find the .desktop files to remove them from dash

Tags: wine, launcher, unity-dash

Messing around with wine, I successfully installed Deus Ex (the original), and created my own custom launcher for it.
Everything works fine.

However the installation created some launchers of its own in the unity dash, namely an "uninstall" and a "safe mode" launcher.

I wish to remove those, but they don't show up in any of these folders:

```
/usr/local/share/applications (doesn't exist)
/usr/share/applications/
~/.local/applications
```

I even ran `find / -name '*.desktop' | grep deus` but found nothing.

Is there a way to just get the path of the launcher straight from the Dash?

Comment: Would they not be in `~/.wine/Drive_C` where the game is installed?

Comment: @MarkKirby I installed it in a custom location, and they're not there. They aren't on my C drive either...

Comment: I am pretty sure they are in `~/.local/share/applications`, which is not in your list... Wine installs its launchers in there. Individual applications may install launchers e.g. on your desktop, but *never*  in `/usr/share/applications`; Wine installs windows applications locally, launchers should (and are) installed locally accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found them: they were under:

```
~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/GOG.com/
```

I guess they escaped the `| grep` search because of capitalization, and I just didn't think to look inside the GOG folder, inside the wine folder...

Running `find /home/orlando/.local/ | grep .desktop | grep deus -i`, while not elegant, found everything and more.

I still don't know how to find a .desktop file's specific location from the Dash, but I guess just looking in the appropriate folders will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is case-sensitive; that is, you must match the pattern with respect to uppercase and lowercase letters. Adapt your `find`-command and search again.

```
find / -name '*.desktop' | grep Deus
```